# Examples of warm blooded vampires?

Tags: vampire

Are there any examples of warm blooded, or warm to the touch vampires in fiction? Would this even be possible?

I know they are cold in Twilight, but I can't remember if it was specified in True Blood, Buffy, Vampire Diaries, or other vampire fiction/lore.

Comment: Closing as an open-ended list question.  'Are there any X?' questions like this are not a good fit for this site, per the [FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Anita Blake universe, vampires are warm after they've fed.  This doesn't always mean on blood, either.  Different vampires have different powers and forms of feeding.

Jean Claude is an incubus and can draw energy and warmth from - er -  another form of energy.  He can also draw energy simply from touch, and has drawn energy from Anita in this way a few times when he was drained, but she refused to share blood.

Some rotting vampires can draw energy from fear, but all forms of feeding bring warmth.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I lost interest in that series after she got involved with the wolf guy, but that is exactly the example I needed.

Comment: I lost interest, too, but for me it was when it went from supernatural tough-girl to not-so-soft-core adult material.

Answer (score 3):

Lukyanenko's Dozor series ([Nightwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_%28Russian_novel%29), [Daywatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_Watch_%28novel%29) etc...) has vampires that are cold when hungry for Power, but warm when sated.

Comment: Good example, thank you! I saw the movie of Night Watch, but didn't think about their temperatures. Thanks!

Comment: @Zoe - I doubt that the movie went into THAT much detail. Typically, the books are far superior :)

Answer (score 3):

[The Dresden Files](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire) have four classes of vampires; at least one (the white court) is / can be warm blooded, although they are not your classic vampire, being closer to Succubi / Incubi.  (I don't recall a specific statement that they are warm (and they can radiate cold when drawing upon the hunger), but since Thomas works as a Hair Stylist for a while, he must not be that noticeably cold to the touch.)  The Red Court vampires are basically disguised Bat Creatures, so they might qualify as well.  I don't remember any details about the Jade court, and the Black Court was your more traditional undead style vampire.

If you count (not very good) movies, '[My Best Friend is a Vampire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_best_friend_is_a_vampire)' makes the distinction between living vampires and the undead, with the protagonist being one of the former.

I THINK Cirque du Freak ([book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirque_du_Freak) / [film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirque_Du_Freak%3a_The_Vampire%27s_Assistant)) also has warm blooded vampires, but I haven't seen it in a while, so I can't say with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

The "vampires" in the Ringworld Trilogy are humans who have lost their sapience and live in the darkness, but they are still quite alive and presumably warm-blooded.

Also, in real life, vampire bats are warm-blooded mammals.